# How to update the splash screen image in app.json in Eas build?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building Expo app with eas build --profile development,
I am trying to update the splash screen in app.json with a new PNG image

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "blue-kiwi",
    "slug": "blue-kiwi",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash1.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.basselturky.bluekiwi"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I did put a new image in assets folder and named it splash1.png
I renamed the path in app.json

```
"splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash1.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
```

The splash screen never update, I did try to rebuild it many times but nothing worked, It keeps showing the old png image

Answer (score 0):

put a new image in assets folder and named it splash.png and remove old

Comment: I tried it before, didn't work.

Comment: make sure dimensions are same  , new image dimensions == old image dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the splash screen not updating on iOS.

Make sure you update app.json and the actual source image, but then manually update it in XCode by searching for SplashScreen.

Mine was located in Project > Project > Images > SplashScreen.

The XCode GUI shows 3 sizes, 1x, 2x, and 3x, but only 1x was populated. Drag and drop the updated file onto 1x to replace the image.

In the sidebar of this GUI, you can locate the source image. Mine was located at /ios/Project/Images.xcassets/SplashScreen.imageset/my-splash.png

Keep app.json in sync just in case Expo does update it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on bare workflow, delete old splash images under `android/app/src/main/res`.

Then use the `expo prebuild` command on terminal to rebuild your splash images.